# String variables and dictionnary output in MiniZinc

Tags: output, minizinc

I have a MiniZinc program in which the variables are mostly integers. Outputs look like

```html
 DELPECH            [4, 5, 7, 10, 11]
 DELPORTE           [2, 3, 6, 8, 10]    
 DELROT         [1, 2, 3, 6, 7] 
 DELRUE         [2, 3, 5, 7, 10]
```

And the underlying code looks like

```html
output([
join([name[ss, 1] ++ 
show([tt | tt in TOPICS where topicSelected[ss,tt]]) ++ "\"
| ss in STUDENTS])]);
```

The problem is that the numbers (between 1 and 11) in fact correspond to topics choices in a scheduling problem, and I would like to display them as such in the final output, i.e. to apply a dictionary looking like 1->"History", 2->"Math", etc.

I was planning to define an array for each student courses[ss] with the name of the corresponding topics, but I don't think it is possible to make variable string arrays. Is there a good way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables of type `var string` are not supported.
But you can index an array of string constants with a `var` variable:

```
array[int] of string: a = ["abra", "ka", "dabra"];

output [ "\n\(a[i]) " ++ show(a[i]) | i in 1..3];
```

I don't know how to avoid the quotes in string output.